# Do I need to take my Work Permit while passing through immigration?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, indian-citizens, china

I got a job offer from China. I received the hard copies of Work Permit and invitation letter. Now, I am going to apply for Chinese Z VISA (work VISA) at Kolkata, India with these hard copies in original. I am just wondering if we stil require the work permit with us while passing through immigration.

Answer (score 2):

Take it with you just in case. While it will be unlikely that you will be asked for it, it is general best practice that one has the most complete documentation at hand when passing through immigration.